# PHP statement if cells in different tables are the same

Tags: php

I need help writing a php echo that checks if two cells are the same in two tables.

The cells are:

posts>id and reblogs>newid

I have the following code to start with:

```
<?php if(!empty($reblogDetails->newid)): ?>
<table><tr><td>
<a href="<?php echo $reblogDetails->newid;?>"><?php echo $newid;?></a>
</td><tr></table>
<?php else: ?>
original upload
<?php endif ?>
```

which I borrowed from another snippet but isn't working.

can anyone help?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Cells... Tables? You should learn the actual terminology and not talk like this is Excel

Comment: I'm not familiar with Excel terminology, sorry that it indirectly unleashed your pedantry.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not completely clear, but I am assuming you want to show the table with an anchor tag only if the posts->id is equal to the reblogDetails->newid?  If that is the case the code you would want would be more like the below.

```
<?php if(!empty($reblogDetails->newid) && $posts->id == $reblogDetails->newid): ?>
<table><tr><td>
<a href="<?php echo $reblogDetails->newid;?>"><?php echo $newid;?></a>
</td><tr></table>
<?php else: ?>
original upload
<?php endif ?>
```

That being said I doubt your anchor tag is doing what you want.  I would anticipate it creating an anchor that looks something like

> `<a href="12">12</a>`

Comment: I don't think `empty($reblogDetails->newid && $posts->id == $reblogDetails->newid)` does what you want.